# Content Type Builder on Strapi production server

Tags: content-type, strapi

Hi i'm new on strapi and i have a problem.

I have a strapi application in production mode so i can't use the Content Type Builder.

I wanna know if is possible to modify the Content Type and how to do that.

On the official docs of Strapi i read that:

> Strapi stores model configuration files (what defines the model schema) in files such as ./src/api/restaurant/content-types/restaurant/schema.json. Due to how Node.js works, in order for changes to take effect, that would require Node to restart the server. This could potentially cause downtime of your production service and likewise these changes should be tracked in some kind of source control.
>
> Generally your "flow" of development would follow the following path:
>
> - Development - Develop your Strapi application locally on your host machine, then push changes into source control
> - Staging - Deploy changes from source control to a "production-like" environment for testing
> - Production - If no other changes are needed, deploy into production
> - Repeat as needed, it is recommended that you properly version and test your application as you go

I have to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It says in the documentation [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/heroku.html#_11-deploy), that its not intended to change the content structure in production. So you have to follow the flow, you mentioned yourself.

> For security reasons, the Content-type Builder plugin is disabled in production. To update content structure, please make your changes locally and deploy again.